# if loop inside a for loop which iterates over a list in R?

Tags: r, list

Complete beginner with R and I've looked around quite a bit but I can't find what I need.

I have a for loop which iterates over a list of values. I want to put an if loop within that for loop, like this:

```
    for (i in list){
    if (i>200){
        print (i)
        }
    }
```

This returns the following warning:

"Warning message:
In if (i > 200) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

and sure enough, the if loop only checks the condition on the very first element in the list.

I understand that this might be because the for loops don't return anything in R, but what's the workaround. How do I solve this?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you provide what you have in `list`? The warning basically telling you that if `i` has longer vector than 1 in it, only the first element will be used. That basically means that there is a problem with the structure of `list`. You can easily reproduce this using something like `l <- list(1:2) ; for (i in l) if (i > 200) print(i)`

Comment: Adding the output of `str(list)` to your question should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:20){
     if (i>10) print(i)
    }
```

In general, conditions are either true or false: 1 or 0. So the condition must always have length 1.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. For me the if statement just compares the very first entry in the list. If the first entry is >200, the whole list prints, otherwise nothing.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what  is in `list`. If `list` is a list of vectors, than `i` is a vector and `i>200` will return a warning message as you are comparing a vector to a single number.

Comment: For loops run though indexes. You use an index to grab each element in the object. If you want to look at the first element in the list, then you subset it. `if (list[[1]][1] > 200) print(list[[1]])`

Comment: Thank you. I realized my list contained vectors. Your help helped me solve this. I tried upvoting but since my account is very new, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detailed enough to know exactly what you want to do.

In general, the `apply` family is very usefull to work with vectors: see the documentation with `?apply`

If you have a list of numeric vectors from which you want to retain only those elements of the vectors that are `> 200` then you could use the following code:

```
# list of numeric vectors
my_list <- list(a = c(201, 199, 202),
                b = c(9, 203, 188),
                c = c(203, 210, 7))


# using the apply family to e.g. calculate a mean
sapply(my_list, mean)
#        a        b        c 
# 200.6667 133.3333 140.0000 

# same thing but now with explicitely naming the vector i
# using an anonymous function
sapply(my_list, function(i) mean(i))
#        a        b        c 
# 200.6667 133.3333 140.0000 

# using a anonymous function to select in the vector what we want
sapply(my_list, function(i){ i[i>200] })
# $a
# [1] 201 202
# 
# $b
# [1] 203
# 
# $c
# [1] 203 210
```

Please let me know whether this is what you want