# for loop with if statements (both iterates over a list) gave warnings in r

Tags: r

I have two lists, each list contains two vectors i.e,

```
x <- list(c(1,2),c(3,4))
y <- list(c(2,4),c(5,6))
z <- list(c(0,0),c(1,1), c(2,3),c(4,5))
```

I would like to use `for` loop to iterate over the first list and `if` statement for the second list as follows:

```
 for (j in 1:seq(x)){
      if(y[[j]] == c(2,4))
        z[[j]] <- c(0,0)
    }
```

I would like to iterate over the first list and for each iteration I would like to give a condition for the second list. My function is complex, so I upload this example which is similar to what I am trying to do with my original function. So that is, I would like to choose the values of `z` based on the values of `y`. For `x` I just want to run the code based on the length of `x`.

When I run it, I got this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In 1:seq(x) : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In if (y[[j]] == c(2, 4)) y[[j]] <- c(0, 0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I search this website and I saw similar question but it is not helpful ([if loop inside a for loop which iterates over a list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093906/if-loop-inside-a-for-loop-which-iterates-over-a-list-in-r)). This question is just for the first part my question. So, it does not help me with my problem.

any help please?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah I expect the code loop for length of `x` and then check `y` based on `y` values give me back `z`.

Comment: I did not get how you get `z` as output? What is the logic of calculation?

Comment: This can be definitely solved if you could make the question more clearer. It's not clear what you want to achieve by `for(j in 1:seq(x))`. What do you want to iterate over?? Please explain that. Also, what is the condition for the second iteration of `x` ? Is `z` the expected output? If so what calculations/logic did you use to achieve `z` as the output. Please make the question more clearer, that might even help you come with a solution yourself.

Comment: I'm unsure what you want to achieve but `x <- list(c(1,2),c(3,4))
y <- list(c(2,4),c(5,6))
z <- list(c(1,1),c(1,1), c(2,3),c(4,5))

for (j in 1:length(x)){
  if(identical(y[[j]], c(2,4))) {
    z[[j]] <- c(0,0)
  }
}`

Comment: @tushaR Thank you for  your amazing comment. It is really so helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first warning is caused by using `seq()` which returns a `[1] 1 2` in combination with the colon operator which creates a sequence between the LHS and RHS. Both values on the left and right of the colon must be of length 1. Otherwise it will take the first element and discard the rest. So `1:seq(x)` is the same as writing `1:1`

The second warning is that the `if` statement gets 2 logical values from your condition:

```
y[[1]] == c(2, 4)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

If you want to test if elements of the vector are the same you can use your notation. If you want to test if the vectors are the same, you can use `all.equal`.

```
isTRUE(all.equal(y[[1]], c(2,4)))
[1] TRUE
```

It returns `TRUE` if vectors are equal (but not `FALSE` if they are not, which is why it needs to be used along with `isTRUE()`).

To get rid of the warnings, you can do:

```
for (j in seq_along(x)){
  if (isTRUE(all.equal(y[[j]], c(2,4)))) {
    z[[j]] <- c(0,0)
  }
}
```

Note: `seq_along()` is a fast primitive for `seq()`

Comment: I meant if `y` has a specific values then `z` will take a specific values based on the values of `y`. So, the values of `z` depends on the values of `y`. for `x`, I just want the code knows that I have two lists and would like to run twice. @Clemens thank a lot for your help.

Comment: in your case, j will take the values 1 and 2 now. In the first iteration (where j`==1`) it will go to `y[[1]] `and find that it is equal to `c(2, 4)`. The first element of `z` will then be 'overwritten' with `c(0, 0)`. (Note: `z[[1]]` already is equal to `c(0, 0)`). In the second iteration (`j==2`) it will do nothing, since `c(5, 6)` is not equal to `c(2, 4)`

Comment: thank a lot. Your help are greatly appreciated. Yes, I understand that "In the second iteration (j==2) it will do nothing, since c(5, 6) is not equal to c(2, 4)" and hence I must use `else` function.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, `seq()` will returns `[1] 1 2`. So, you need to use `j in seq(x)` or `j in 1:length(x)`.
and for the second part, as the command you used generates `TRUE` and `FALSE` as many as the elements in the vectors, you can use `setequal(x,y)`. This command will check whether two objects are equal or not. two objects can be vectors, dataframes, etc, and the result is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
The final code can be:

```
for (j in 1:length(x)){
  if (setequal(y[[j]], c(2,4)) == TRUE) {
    z[[j]] <- c(0,0)
  }
}
```

or:

```
for (j in seq(x)){
  if (setequal(y[[j]], c(2,4)) == TRUE) {
    z[[j]] <- c(0,0)
  }
}
```